# SharePoint 2013 picture gallery preview not working

Tags: web-part, picture-library

I created a picture gallery in under a branded site collection and uploaded an image. While uploading the image the preview of the image is not shown. Hence the Picture library slide show web part is also not showing the images.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: What URL is it trying to load (right-click and View Image)? Can you follow that link?

Comment: I am able to open that image seperately. However right-click view image doesnt show.

Comment: Please check the user permissions for site and for the library too.

Comment: If it allows the user to upload an image and it creates the item, then they have Contribute rights at least.

Comment: It looks like the thumbnail isn't being created. If you can't right-click and load it into the browser, then it simply doesn't exist. Are you getting a 404?

Comment: Thanks for the comment Niranjan. The permissions looks fine. I am seeing it as Site Collection admin

Comment: Thanks jpollar - The thumbnail is getting created. I checked in SP designer. When I see the source the image source is forming like this. http://xxxxx/xxx/TempLib/_w/_.jpg. So the image name is not coming. If I edit the image name in the developer tool, it is working fine. Not sure why the image name is not coming.